# Open angular 2 component from a link in email with querystring parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component for which I wish to provide the deep link with query string parameters, clicking on which opens the component in the browser.

Example:

exmaple.com/MyComponent?Id=10

I wish to provide a link in the email with the specific Id which opens up the component and shows the information for Id=10 in the modal which I have inside the same component.

I do not wish to provide any router link in the html as its only the single component.

I have basic understand of routing in angular 2 but not sure how it works without the router link.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using ActivatedRoute, In your MyComponent.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params['Id']);
     });
}
```